# Grasshopper vs Tarantula?

Tags: entomology, behaviour, arachnology, predation

This past weekend (October 2021) while hiking west of the VLA in New Mexico (near Datil, NM, ~2200m elevation) my wife and I came across a strange sight. A small (5cm long), likely immature, [*Aphonopelma peloncillo*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aphonopelma_peloncillo) walking near the trail. That was not particularly unusual this time of year. However, as it moved we noticed that it was being followed by a grasshopper, which was roughly as long as the small tarantula. While the tarantula was still, the grasshopper would walk (not hop) up behind it, the tarantula would notice and skitter forward 10-15 cm, and the process repeated itself over a distance of a meter or so. Several times it appeared that the grasshopper made to attack the rear end of the tarantula. Eventually the tarantula said enough is enough and skittered out of sight rapidly. The scene was mesmerizing enough that neither of us got out our phones to take pictures (sigh).

Based on pictures at [insectidentification.org](https://www.insectidentification.org/insect-description.php?identification=Differential-Grasshopper) and [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differential_grasshopper) and going by memory (stupid - no pictures), the grasshopper was likely a Differential grasshopper, *Melanoplus differentialis*. The size (females up to 5 cm) and territory fit. Sources given indicate they eats plants. Given the season it seems unlikely to me that, were they female, they would still be laying eggs - one of the few reasons I can think of they would try to drive off a tarantula.

Is this a known behavior for a grasshopper? Was it protecting territory (do grasshoppers even have territory)? It is hard to imagine that the grasshopper was attempting to prey on the tarantula. Any information (journal articles welcome - I've searched on Web of Science with no success) available?

Comment: Welcome to Biology.SE. Interesting question — is there any chance you could provide more details about the grasshopper? Knowing what species it was could help with you getting a better answer. I do know that some species of grasshopper are omnivorous, but I don't know whether they've ever been reported to attack spiders (let alone a tarantula).

Comment: What an interesting observation! Perhaps it was a kind of carnivorous orthopteran? I would suggest using [BugGuide's Browse tab](https://bugguide.net/node/view/73/bgpage) to narrow down candidates, and check the Data tab for any likely taxon to make sure it is found in New Mexico.